# Distributing iOS App internally

Tags: ios, app-store, distribution

I have been looking into the ways of distributing an iOS application internally in our company. One thing I cant really find any information on is in the Enterprise program, what do they mean when they say:

> Distribute Your In-house Apps Distribute your proprietary, in-house
>   iOS apps to employees or members of your organization. You can also
>   securely host and wirelessly distribute or update in-house apps to
>   employees, keeping them current anywhere, anytime.

Are they referring to AD-Hoc, or is this some special way of distributing apps for enterprises?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Apple Enterprise Developer program is meant for an organisation to build and distribute apps within their company to their employees only.

It costs $299 per year and requires that the organisation has a DUNS (Dun and Bradstreet) number to register with.

http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Specifically, you can still develop apps using a regular development provisioning profile and then release the app to your employees with a distribution profile, but it is on this phase that you get two choices:

1) Ad-hoc (limited to 100 devices using their UDID)

2) In house. (the whole point of buying an enterprise account)

A screenshot is attached below for your reference: (excuse the poor editing)

[image: Enterprise Distribution Screenshot]

Comment: No worries :) If your company/organisation is baed in the UK and you need to get a DUNS number, this is the link: http://salesmarketing.dnb.co.uk/find_my_company/

Answer (score 1):

Ad Hoc and Enterprise distribution are 2 different things.  Ad Hoc requires provisioning the app with each devices UDID, 99 max (plus the developers 1).  The iOS Enterprise enrollment allows unlimited distribution strictly to employees of an enrolled D&B rated corporation
(the D&B corporate rating info includes the employee count).

Answer (score 0):

The ad-hoc provision profile is for signing test releases of your app for mass testing purpose. You can have maximum 100 testers of your app.

If you want to distribute you application for production usage to your company, you should enroll in the "iOS Developer Enterprise Program ".

Answer (score 0):

With an Enterprise Developer's license, you can do OTA deployment as well. http://martiancraft.com/blog/2017/02/creating-ios-app-download-pages/  as an example.

Answer (score -1):

Just use https://testflightapp.com :-) HockeyApp also offers beta distribution functionality: http://www.hockeyapp.net/distribution